# Flutter app crash on release mode while terminating agora call

Tags: android, flutter, dart, agora.io

I have a flutter app where I implemented agora. The app works totally fine on debug mode but crashes on release mode while I end the call. The idea is to end the call and show a dialog box with call duration and other details. The app crashes just before showing the dialog. Works fine on debug mode shows dialog but doesn't shows on release mode and app crashes. The repos stores a log as record for future which is working fine and returns data as expected. I don't know what I did wrong.

I have been stuck in this for too long, any help or guidance would be really appreciated. Thank you

Followwing code is while I click the end button to terminate a call

```
Future<dynamic> _onCallEnd(BuildContext context) async {
  setState(() {    // some states for ui 
    isStopped = true;
    hostOnline = false;
  });
  callEndLog();    // creating a log 
}

Future<dynamic> callEndLog() async {
    await _con.callEndLog();    
}
```

Following is my controller

```
callEndLog() async{
  await videoCallRepo.callEndLog().then((value) {
    if(value != null){
      showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return TerminateChatPopup(
            // some params
          );
        },
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Following is my repo

```
Future<dynamic> callEndLog() async{
  final String apiUrl = "${GlobalConfiguration().getValue('api_base_url')}contact-complete/video";
  final client = new http.Client();
  Map data = {
    // some data
  };
  String body = json.encode(data);
  final response = await client.post(
    apiUrl, headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'},body: body,
  );
  if(response.body!=null){
    var bodyRes = json.decode(response.body);
    if(bodyRes['success']){
      return bodyRes;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Some issues found');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have came across same problem and just recently fixed it.

Problem lies in allowing your build to be in release version.

Please follow this instruction: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

important: signingConfigs.release